# endless Unable to find or serve resource error while there is resource with Chromium

Tags: jsf, chromium

I want to show a video in my web page. my video is in `resources/videos` folder. and it is 15 MB. I added video with html `video` tag :

```
<video id="video" preload="none" loop="loop">
    <source src="#{resource['videos/video.mp4']}" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

when I start the project I see this error in a endless loop

```
Apr 23, 2018 11:49:15 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, videos/video.mp4.
Apr 23, 2018 11:49:15 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: 
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:407)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:358)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:240)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:402)
    ... 31 more
```

it says unable to find video.mp4 but I know video.mp4 is available under `resources/videos` folder and also chromium starts to play the video. Also if I open the project on Firefox there is no error. so how can I solve this problem ?

Also I tried different videos with different size but always I get same error

I am using `Mojarra 2.2.12`, `Netbeans 8.2`, `Chromium 65.0.3325.181`, `Firefox 59.0.2`

Comment: tried with a video of 1MB?

Comment: @Kukeltje actually I did not try. but if I removed video tag error was gone. I will try and update the question. thanks.

Comment: @Kukeltje, i tried with 1MB video. but still I get errors